# Уместно и грамотно ли будет поставить тире там, где правила пунктуации его не требуют?

Tags: пунктуация

> По прихоти судьбы его возлюбленная невеста заодно и дочь
>   могущественного союзника.

Мне не читается. Тире исправит восприятие? Чем оно может быть обосновано?

*По прихоти судьбы его возлюбленная невеста – заодно и дочь могущественного союзника.*

Comment: Восприятие здесь испорчено употреблением "заодно" без глагола (обычно напрямую указывается, что с чем заодно _делается_ - "заодно является" и т. п.) и вне устойчивого сочетания "_кто с кем_ заодно" - этому слову требуются явные "координаты". Надо заменять на простое "ещё".

Comment: Саш, давай ответом!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По правилам действительно тире не ставится, если между подлежащим и сказуемым -существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица: *Грач, конечно, птица умная и самостоятельная, но голоса у него нет (Пауст.); Мой отец для меня друг и наставник; Москва теперь порт пяти морей.*

Но тире возможно при акцентировании сказуемого (обычно в стилистических целях): *По прихоти судьбы его возлюбленная невеста – заодно и дочь могущественного союзника.* Оно обосновано интонацией.

Другой вопрос - о "заодно". Это, конечно, разговорное употребление. Если бы это была речь героя, употребление его было бы стилистически обосновано, ведь у слова есть и значение "одновременно", но оно разговорное. В авторской речи всё-таки следует заменить на "ещё".

Answer (score 2):

ЗАОДНО, нареч. 1. Вместе, сообща, в согласии. Действовать з. Быть з. с кем-л. 2. Разг. Одновременно с чем-л. другим; попутно. Иду по делу, з. навещу 
друга.

Тире здесь ставится по правилам (**интонационное деление предложения на две части при необходимости**): тире отделяет состав подлежащего от состава сказуемого, так как наречие "заодно" удобно отнести  к группе сказуемого.

Розенталь [§79. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm#%D0%B7_01)

Общая позиция Розенталя при решении задач на эту тему: Постановка тире в этих случаях имеет целью интонационно расчленить предложение и облегчить восприятие его содержания.

Comment: Это касается случая, когда сказуемое предшествует подлежащему, например: Прекрасный человек Иван Иванович! (Гоголь). По правилу тире нет.
Постановка тире в этом случае подчеркивает интонационное членение предложения на два состава, например: Славные люди – соседи мои! (Некрасов); Хорошая сторона – Сибирь! (Горький)

Comment: Это касается многих случаев, не этого одного. Розенталь постоянно отмечает возможность постановки тире для интонационного членения предложения. Вот пример из классики : Минута с ней - небесный рай! Здесь падежная форма входит в состав подлежащего

Comment: Ну, здесь-то всё согласно правилам: тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными им. падежом, ни обстоятельства, ни вводного слова, ни частицы между ними нет.

Comment: Между подлежащим и сказуемым находится дополнение "с ней". Оно относится к подлежащему, и тире ставится, чтобы разделить группу подлежащего и сказуемого. Сравнить: Стихи для вас одна забава. Это общее дополнение, определять состав подлежащего и сказуемого здесь не требуется, поэтому тире не ставится. Правила же не придумываются, а имеют определенный смысл и объяснение. Они на конкретных примерах  учат нас общему принципу решения  пунктуационных задач,  чтобы потом применять этот принцип для самостоятельных решений.

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант:

**По прихоти судьбы, его возлюбленная невеста заодно и дочь могущественного союзника.**

Обособив обстоятельство-детерминант, можно обойтись без постановки тире, так как именно этот оборот мешает нормальному прочтению и пониманию предложения.

Пример с обособлением:

Теперь, **по прихоти судьбы,** я веду следствие по делу о злодейском убийстве государя. [А. И. Алдан-Семенов. Красные и белые (1966-1973)]